# Edit FLASH animation

Tags: flash, swf

I want to edit Flash animation.
I have fla, swf and swf fiels, but How I should open them?

Is there any possibility to edit swf file without fla or swd file?

Comment: You should edit the fla file :) I wouldn't know of any other way to alter the contents of an swf.

Comment: I tried to edit it with adobe flash cs 5.5 and macromedia flash mx(year 2002 lol) but both told me that can't open FLA file, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Flash is not backwards compatible. So I'm guessing the .fla is an older version. (For example, cs3-created files can't be opened by cs5). Your only option would be to find out what cs the file was created with and open/edit it with that version.

Comment: Edit the swf file is impossible, as far as I know (and I've been working with flash for lot of years)

Comment: But perhaps you know how to define CS where file was created? ?

Comment: What error are you getting with Flash cs 5.5? It should open without a problem, sounds like you have a corrupt file.

Comment: @Michiel Standaert: New versions can open any old version but can't save it past the immediately-preceding version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened source FLA with CS3.

Also I managed to decompile SWF and delete or change frames, sprites, images, texts and scripts I need.

So to edit ready swf, we need to decompile it, and then compile again.